# Commandlet with Parameter accepting ByPropertyName works for one parameter but not for other parameter

Tags: powershell-7.0

Get-Command Accepts both `Module` and `Name` using `ByPropertyName`

```
help Get-Command -Parameter * 
-Module <System.String[]>
    Position?                    named
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)

-Name <System.String[]>
    Position?                    0
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName, ByValue)
```

However

```
[PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'dir'} | Get-command    /*This Works*/
```

but

```
[PSCustomObject]@{Module = 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive'} | Get-command    /*This is NOT Working*/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The byvalue of name screws it up because of its higher precedence over the pipe.  Here's a workaround, `*` for the name:

```
[pscustomobject]@{module = 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive'} | get-command -name *

CommandType     Name                        Version    Source
-----------     ----                        -------    ------
Function        Compress-Archive            1.2.5      Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive
Function        Expand-Archive              1.2.5      Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive
```

Even this way name is still required.

```
'Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive' | get-command -module { $_ } -name *
```

Comment: Grest! Thanks for answering it. It worked but what is the use of * here?

Comment: byvalue takes precedence when piped in, so -name has to be set to something